# PayPal Smart Buttons returns me JSON error

Tags: json, paypal, client, response, integration

I'm implementing Express Checkout Integration in PHP (using PayPal Smart Buttons) but I get an error when I try to pay.

The error is triggered when the `createOrder` function is called. I believe the error lies in the server side, because the `fetch` is being executed successfully and the server generates an ORDER ID, however it does not properly pass the ORDER ID to the client and I end up with the following error:

> Error: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0

I don't know what could be wrong as I'm using the SDK provided by PayPal

My client

```
 <script>
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
        paypal.Buttons({

            // Set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('*http://localhost/test/createorder.php', {
                    method: 'post'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(data) {
                    return data.orderID;
                });
            },

            // Finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/' + data.orderID + '/capture/', {
                    method: 'post'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(details) {
                    // Show a success message to the buyer
                    alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
                });
            },
            onError: function(err){
                    alert(err)
            }


        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
```

My server

```
<?php

namespace Sample\CaptureIntentExamples;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
//1. Import the PayPal SDK client that was created in `Set up Server-Side SDK`.
use Sample\PayPalClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCreateRequest;

class CreateOrder
{

// 2. Set up your server to receive a call from the client
  /**
   *This is the sample function to create an order. It uses the
   *JSON body returned by buildRequestBody() to create an order.
   */
  public static function createOrder($debug=false)
  {
    $request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
    $request->prefer('return=representation');
    $request->body = self::buildRequestBody();
   // 3. Call PayPal to set up a transaction
    $client = PayPalClient::client();
    $response = $client->execute($request);
    if ($debug)
    {
      print "Status Code: {$response->statusCode}\n";
      print "Status: {$response->result->status}\n";
      print "Order ID: {$response->result->id}\n";
      print "Intent: {$response->result->intent}\n";
      print "Links:\n";
      foreach($response->result->links as $link)
      {
        print "\t{$link->rel}: {$link->href}\tCall Type: {$link->method}\n";
      }

      // To print the whole response body, uncomment the following line
      // echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }

    // 4. Return a successful response to the client.
    return $response;
  }

  /**
     * Setting up the JSON request body for creating the order with minimum request body. The intent in the
     * request body should be "AUTHORIZE" for authorize intent flow.
     *
     */
    private static function buildRequestBody()
    {
        return array(
            'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
            'application_context' =>
                array(
                    'return_url' => 'https://example.com/return',
                    'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel'
                ),
            'purchase_units' =>
                array(
                    0 =>
                        array(
                            'amount' =>
                                array(
                                    'currency_code' => 'USD',
                                    'value' => '220.00'
                                )
                        )
                )
        );
    }
}


/**
 *This is the driver function that invokes the createOrder function to create
 *a sample order.
 */
if (!count(debug_backtrace()))
{
  CreateOrder::createOrder(true);
}
?>
```

I got the code from PayPal documentation.

UPDATE

When I replace `return $response` with something like this:

```
 $orderID=['orderID'=>$response->result->id];
 echo json_encode($orderID, true);
```

and remove this part of the code:

```
  if ($debug)
        {
          print "Status Code: {$response->statusCode}\n";
          print "Status: {$response->result->status}\n";
          print "Order ID: {$response->result->id}\n";
          print "Intent: {$response->result->intent}\n";
          print "Links:\n";
          foreach($response->result->links as $link)
          {
            print "\t{$link->rel}: {$link->href}\tCall Type: {$link->method}\n";
          }

          // To print the whole response body, uncomment the following line
          // echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        }
```

it partially works. The PayPal lightbox opens up with the generated token, however it closes down right after. When I try to access it directly using the URL, it says "Something went wrong".

Comment: Add debugging to the server-side create order so you can see what's going on.

Comment: Eveyrthing seems to be working normally, except for this `return $response`, shouldn't I return only the orderID/id? `$response->result->id` , it's returning the whole response and there's no orderID the server side, only id.

Comment: It depends on what your client-side expects to receive.  If your client-side parses json and reads the result.id , it's fine.

Comment: The key thing to understand is that you are designing the middleware interface between the client side and your server. PayPal has not designed this interface. So the spec is up to you, and there is absolutely no reason it needs to be the same as the PayPal API spec of your server communication with PayPal.  All that matters is that you at least transfer the OrderID correctly somehow.

Comment: Yeah I got it now. I'm doing this in my server side: `$id=["id"=>$response->result->id];
    echo json_encode($res, true);` which returns me: `{"id":"1BT6339175263640W"}` my client side `return data.id`. It opens up the PayPal Lightbox, shows the login inputs, but closes right after. I checked and the token is being sent to the URL. Same thing with the credit card option, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: "I'm alerting" the client results. I got this: `Error: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: You'll have better luck with `console.log`, `console.warn` rather than alert, but as it's undefined you probably need to go even further back to see what went wrong with where you are getting it.

Comment: The fact that you can log in is interesting, if it really is making use of that id. I would look for debug information from PayPal's own logging in the console.

Comment: The console just gives me: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at http://localhost/test/test/second.php:47:27`

`Error: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at jr.error (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=client-id:1:58508);` It seems like I'm not passing the geenrated order id to the client, however, as far as I know, it should work. I'm watching the network tab and everything seems to be working normally in the server side. I'm probably doing something wrong but I cannot figure it out. I also get this error `unexpected end of JSON input`

Comment: console.log the thing you are doing .id on, and the thing you are trying to parse as JSON.

Comment: Gives me `Uncaught Error: Expected an order id to be passed`, `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`and `update_client_config_error`. It really seems like the server isn't returning the id? Or there's something wrong with my client? I have tried even basic examples in order to see what could be wrong but same result. I'm not used to fetch tho, I use Ajax, although it shouldn't be a problem. So the problem is either I'm not correctly passing the id from the server to the client or there's something wrong in my client because all the rest seems to be working just well.

Comment: I have tried with ajax and it works, but not with fetch.

Answer (score 4):

I finally found a solution making some modifications in the back end and the front end.

I got this working by

commenting this part of the code

```
  if ($debug=true)
    {
      print "Status Code: {$response->statusCode}\n";
      print "Status: {$response->result->status}\n";
      print "Order ID: {$response->result->id}\n";
      print "Intent: {$response->result->intent}\n";
      print "Links:\n";
      foreach($response->result->links as $link)
      {
        print "\t{$link->rel}: {$link->href}\tCall Type: {$link->method}\n";
      }

      // To print the whole response body, uncomment the following line
      // echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
```

replacing `return $response` with

```
$json_obj= array('id'=>$response->result->id);
$jsonstring = json_encode($json_obj);
echo $jsonstring;
```

and adjusting the currency as well in the front end

The wrong currency option was throwing an exception, causing the PayPal lightbox to close (as well as the credit card option).

Comment: Looking for this answer for sooo long! I can't believe a company as big as Paypal can have such WRONG and incomplete documentation on its main purpose... accepting payments on the web!

Comment: Ronald, unfortunately, as I have noticed, not only PayPal has such poor documentation when it comes about this kind of integration. They provide a lot of documentation but they don't do the basics: to give an example on how to implement their API. I have left a feedback on their page.